# Select functions to import from module

Tags: javascript

If we have a module like:

```
const ourModule = (() => {
  const add = (a,b) a+b

  const sub = (a,b) return a-b

  return { add, sub }
})();

export default ourModule;
```

So we import like:

```
import ourModule from 'path'
```

And call the functions like:

```
ourModule.add(1,2)
```

But how we can import it to use it directly?
like just `add(1,2)` instead of `ourModule.add(1,2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use named exports instead:

```
export const add = (a,b) => a+b;
export const sub = (a,b) => a-b;
```

Then they can be imported like:

```
import { add } from './your/module';
```

Comment: so with this syntax `ourModule = (() => { stuff })();` is not possible to archive this?

Comment: @Sevila no as you can't destructure a function. You're exporting a function, you can only destructure objects and arrays.

Comment: It's not clear why you're wrapping this in an IIFE; the source file is already an isolated module, so you don't need to create a closure like that. Any local declarations in your module file are only available inside of the module.

Comment: Was using like that, to avoid an event listener inside the file be activated, when the import occurs, using named export it will be trigger right away when the file is imported. So I guess the best will remove the listener from this module and use named export.

Comment: Wrapping in an IIFE doesn't solve that; the logic will still be triggered since you're calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for destructuring imports:

```
function add() {

}

function sub() {

}

module.exports = { add, sub };
```

Then you can do:
`import { add, sub } from "./MyModule"`